# How to override custom severity icon in a p:confirmDialog

Tags: primefaces, confirm-dialog

How can I override the severity facet of confirmDialog ?

For example,

```
<f:facet name="severity">
    <h:outputText rendered="#{severity eq 'alert'}" styleClass="ui-icon icon_warning ui-confirm-dialog-severity"></h:outputText>
    <h:outputText rendered="#{severity eq 'info' }" styleClass="ui-icon icon_info ui-confirm-dialog-severity"></h:outputText>
    <h:outputText rendered="#{severity eq 'warn' }" styleClass="ui-icon icon_error ui-confirm-dialog-severity"></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Jasper Thanks for suggestion.. It would be  of more help if i can see the composition of confirmDialog, so i know where I can insert my severity facet.

Comment: There is no such facet. Have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml. Just use `<p:confirm icon="..."/>`.

Comment: Do we have a template area for severity ?

Comment: I improved your title. Please look at the differences and read [ask] about good/bad titles

Comment: What is a template area (or what should it do?)